# I want to pass a variable form controller action to a view asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want a way to make me able to pass a variable data NOT A CLASS DATA from an action in home controller to a view and I wan't a very simple way like a viewbag or something I was searching the whole day and I saw viewdata viewbag tempdata sessions and what I want to do is I have a simple asp.net mvc program which will ask me 10 questions in time table and when I finish answering the 10 questions it will redirects me to a view(index) which will say something like "Congratulations you have correctly answered `CorrectAnswers` from total of 10 questions" I couldn't make it in my code so here is the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Question(Models.QuestionVM model)
    {
        int? cAnswers = model.CAnswers;
        ViewBag.CA = cAnswers;
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        int correctAnswer = model.Number1 * model.Number2;
        if (model.SelectedAnswer == correctAnswer)
        {
            cAnswers += 1; //here is the code that must increment the number of correct answers whenever the useranswer is equal to correctanswer
        }
        if (model.ID < 10)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Question", new { id = ++model.ID });
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); // the method that displays the final results
        }
    }
```

and the view I want to pass variable to (Index):

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div style="text-align: center;">
<h1 style="font-size:125px; color: darkorange; font-weight: 900; 
">Congratulations!</h1>
<h2 style="font-size:75px; color: darkorange; font-weight: 900; ">You Have 
Answered @ViewBag.CA From 10 Questions</h2>
</div>
```

and the QuestionVM class:

```
public class QuestionVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; } // the question number
    public int Number1 { get; set; }
    public int Number2 { get; set; }
    public List<int> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Answer")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an answer")]
    public int? SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
    public int? CAnswers { get; set; } // Here is the variable that I'm trying to increment
}
```

Comment: @Shyju it is already before the `return` line or do you mean another thing

Comment: So what specifically is not working ?

Comment: @Shyju when I run the code it will get me to index page and says "Congratulations! You Have Answered (and then nothing here but I want to get the number of correct answer here) From 10 Questions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewBag does not work with Redirection. You need to use TempData when you are redirecting to another action method.

```
TempData["CorrectAnswers"] = 4;
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

and in the `Index` action or view, read the value from `TempData["CorrectAnswers"]`

```
<h2>You Have Answered @TempData["CorrectAnswers"] From 10 Questions</h2>
```

Comment: I have changed the `viewbag.CA` to `tempData["CA"]` and still not showing any thing in the index view

Comment: if you can make more clear so I can solve it it will be awesome

Comment: tempData["CA"]!=TempData["CA"] . Also did you make the change in the view as well ?

Comment: where should I write the code you wrote? Yes I have changed the view

Comment: Setting the TempData inside your action method before retuning the redirection

Comment: I can't understand the last comment can you please write the code you wrote but in the code in the answer to see the place I should put code in

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve it is that before redirecting you store the value in session:

```
Session["cAnswers"] = cAnswers;
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

And then create another action for Index, fetch the value from session and fill it in ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.CA = Session["cAnswers"];
    return View();
}
```